# How to organize code in rebol?

Tags: import, module, code-organization, rebol

Whats the best way to organize code in Rebol? 
(Rebol2, not Rebol3. Rebol3 will have `import`, as it seems.)

Is the `do %myfunctions.r`-style all that is needed? There is no real `package` statement like in Java, or `#include` like in C?

Do community-approved naming conventions exist?  
Could http://www.rebol.it/power-mezz/mezz/module.html be considered a standard?

I read somewhere that I could build my own module system as well. But this seems not like a sensible approach to me.

Is this discussion doomed as Rebol3 will be finished soon? ;-)

Comment: In answer to your 'doomed' question, the uptick in interest following the open-sourcing of Rebol is encouraging. I guess it remains to be seen if this becomes a sustained effort that delivers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some subjects I know use my [include.r](http://www.rebol.org/view-script.r?script=ladislav-include.r), released under Apache 2.0 now. It is not a module system but you may find it useful.

Comment: Looks promising. If no other answers are given I will accept this one.